# How do I repeat this code for a given amount of times

Tags: python-3.x

I have a loop to turn a motor on, turn it off and sleep for 60 minutes, then repeat. I need the loop to repeat 8 times and then turn off completely.

```
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
import time

1.        kit = MotorKit()
2.
3.        while True:
4.        endtime = time.time() + 1
5.        while time.time() < endtime:
6.        kit.motor1.throttle = 1
7.        pass
8.        print('endtime passed')
9.        kit.motor1.throttle = 0
10.       time.sleep(60*60)
11.       print('done sleeping')
```

I expect the loop to run for 1 second, then sleep for 60 minutes, then repeat. I want it to repeat 8 times.

Comment: I just added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are kind of new to Python and programming in general. Since you know that you are going to execute the same activity for 8 times, you should use a `for` loop instead of a `while`. You can use a `while` loop, but this will make your code more readable.

Use the module `time` in order to get the curren time, and run a while loop for one second using the condition `time.time() < t_end`. Inside the while loop, put the logic you want to execute, in this case it is just the line `kit.motor1.throttle = 1`.

I think you can use the following:

```py
import time

from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit

kit = MotorKit()

for _ in range(8):
    t_end = time.time() + 1
    while time.time() < t_end:
        kit.motor1.throttle = 1

    print('endtime passed')
    kit.motor1.throttle = 0
    time.sleep(60*60)
    print('done sleeping')
```